# Get struct from C++ dll into a C# application

Tags: c++, dll, struct

I'm learning C# and have some experience with it. For a small project I need to implement a C++ dll into my C# app. It is a licenseplate recognition sdk.I can initialize it, so calling to this C++ code is working. But I have a problem to receive a struct back from the c++ code with strings in it. I tried a lot, read here a lot, but I don't get it working. This is C# side:

```
[DllImport("D:\\processor.dll", EntryPoint = "StartALPR",   CallingConvention   = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
[return:MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)]
 public static extern TMyData StartALPR(TImageSource tImageSource);
```

The C# struct TMyData :

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]  

public  struct  TMyData
{

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)]        
    public  string PlateString;


   [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)]
   public string PlateXML;


   [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)]
   public  string LastError;

};
```

And this is the method we call to send tImageSource which contains a string with a filepath to an image to analyze.

alprResult = StartALPR(tImageSource);

The file is analyzed, so that's working. I can see the plate strings in the output of VS2015.
But I'm expecting a struct "alprResult" back as defined in TMydata, but I get an exception that the method sign is not compatible with the pinvoke sign. The only information I have is an example of how to use this dll/code in C++. This is the C++ code :

```
TImageSource SImageSource;
TMyData *pd;

/* Set input image */
SImageSource.MyImageFile = AnsiString(CarImage).c_str();
Memo1->Lines->Clear();

/* Starting plate detect and recognition */
pd = StartALPR(&SImageSource);

/* Standard XML result, the plate datas with numbers and positions */
Memo1->Lines->Add(pd->PlateXML);

/* last error message */
Memo2->Lines->Add(pd->LastError);

/* Best characters on plate */
Edit1->Text = pd->PlateString;
```

This is the C++ struct from the same example :

```
   struct TMyData;
   typedef TMyData *PMyData;

      struct TMyData
      {
      /**
      PlateString: Best license plate number of the plate group
      */
   const char * PlateString;        
   /**
  PlateXML: Plate group data in standard XML string
  */
  const char * PlateXML;        
  /**
  LastError: Laast config error ex: bad file extensions         ..                 Default: empty
   */
   const char * LastError;      

        };
```

How can I use this in C#?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I actually had to solve a similar issue to this recently.  I simply serialized the data into a struct and shipped it over a local zeromq socket.

```
//
//  Weather update server in C++
//  Binds PUB socket to tcp://*:5556
//  Publishes random weather updates
//
//  Olivier Chamoux <olivier.chamoux@fr.thalesgroup.com>
//
#include <zmq.hpp>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#if (defined (WIN32))
#include <zhelpers.hpp>
#endif

#define within(num) (int) ((float) num * random () / (RAND_MAX + 1.0))

int main () {

    //  Prepare our context and publisher
    zmq::context_t context (1);
    zmq::socket_t publisher (context, ZMQ_PUB);
    publisher.bind("tcp://*:5556");
    publisher.bind("ipc://weather.ipc");                // Not usable on Windows.

    //  Initialize random number generator
    srandom ((unsigned) time (NULL));
    while (1) {

        int zipcode, temperature, relhumidity;

        //  Get values that will fool the boss
        zipcode     = within (100000);
        temperature = within (215) - 80;
        relhumidity = within (50) + 10;

        //  Send message to all subscribers
        zmq::message_t message(20);
        snprintf ((char *) message.data(), 20 ,
            "%05d %d %d", zipcode, temperature, relhumidity);
        publisher.send(message);

    }
    return 0;
}
```

and now the client

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;

using ZeroMQ;

namespace Examples
{
    static partial class Program
    {
        public static void WUClient(string[] args)
        {
            //
            // Weather update client
            // Connects SUB socket to tcp://127.0.0.1:5556
            // Collects weather updates and finds avg temp in zipcode
            //
            // Author: metadings
            //

            if (args == null || args.Length < 2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Usage: ./{0} WUClient [ZipCode] [Endpoint]", AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName);
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine("    ZipCode   The zip code to subscribe. Default is 72622 Nürtingen");
                Console.WriteLine("    Endpoint  Where WUClient should connect to.");
                Console.WriteLine("              Default is tcp://127.0.0.1:5556");
                Console.WriteLine();
                if (args.Length < 1)
                    args = new string[] { "72622", "tcp://127.0.0.1:5556" };
                else
                    args = new string[] { args[0], "tcp://127.0.0.1:5556" };
            }

            string endpoint = args[1];

            // Socket to talk to server
            using (var context = new ZContext())
            using (var subscriber = new ZSocket(context, ZSocketType.SUB))
            {
                string connect_to = args[1];
                Console.WriteLine("I: Connecting to {0}…", connect_to);
                subscriber.Connect(connect_to);

                /* foreach (IPAddress address in WUProxy_GetPublicIPs())
                    {
                        var epgmAddress = string.Format("epgm://{0};239.192.1.1:8100", address);
                        Console.WriteLine("I: Connecting to {0}…", epgmAddress);
                        subscriber.Connect(epgmAddress);
                    }
                } */

                // Subscribe to zipcode
                string zipCode = args[0];
                Console.WriteLine("I: Subscribing to zip code {0}…", zipCode);
                subscriber.Subscribe(zipCode);

                // Process 10 updates
                int i = 0;
                long total_temperature = 0;
                for (; i < 20; ++i)
                {
                    using (var replyFrame = subscriber.ReceiveFrame())
                    {
                        string reply = replyFrame.ReadString();

                        Console.WriteLine(reply);
                        total_temperature += Convert.ToInt64(reply.Split(' ')[1]);
                    }
                }
                Console.WriteLine("Average temperature for zipcode '{0}' was {1}°", zipCode, (total_temperature / i));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I did that @πάντα ῥεῖ

Comment: Thank you Chuck Norris. I did solve it another way, It was returning a pointer.